# updating method using content values

Tags: java, android, database, android-studio, null

**Helper**

```
public boolean mMessagesSent(String ID,int Data) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
    contentValues.put(KEY_ID, ID);
    contentValues.put(KEY_MESSAGES_SENT, Data);
    db.update(TABLE_USER_DATA, contentValues, null, null);
    return true;
}
```

**Activity**

```
mainData.mTotalMessages("MyData", +1);
        mainData.mTotalMessagesSent("MyData",+1);
        mainData.mMessages(MessageRecieverId,+1);
        mainData.mMessagesSent(MessageRecieverId,+1);
```

Is this the correct method to update data... I want to increase the int value of data by 1 so i have put +1 but still the value is empty when i retrieve data

**CODE AFTER FOLLOWING FIRST ANSWER**

```
public boolean mMessagesSent(String ID,int Data) {
    MainData mainData = new MainData(getApplicationContext());
    SQLiteDatabase db = mainData.getWritableDatabase();
    String newId = ID;
    int newData = Data;
    MainData helper = new MainData(this); //Change the name to your Helper Class name
    Cursor data = helper.getData();
    while (data.moveToNext()) {
        newId = data.getString(data.getColumnIndex("Data"));
        newData = data.getInt(data.getColumnIndex("TotalMessagesSent"));
    }
    ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
    contentValues.put(KEY_DATA, newId);
    contentValues.put(KEY_MESSAGES_SENT, (newData + 1)); //Change the value of newData(which is actually your old value) by incrementing
    db.update(TABLE_USER_DATA, contentValues, null, null);
    return true;
}
```

**FETCHING**

```
final MainData myDBHlpr = new MainData(getActivity());

    Cursor csr = myDBHlpr.getAllQuestions(getActivity());
    while (csr.moveToNext()) {

        mTotalMessagesSent.setText(csr.getString(1));
        mTotalMessagesRecieved.setText(csr.getString(csr.getColumnIndex("TotalMessagesRecieved")));
        mTotalMessages.setText(csr.getString(csr.getColumnIndex("TotalMessages")));

    }

        csr.close();
```

Answer (score 0):

> Is this the correct method to update data... I want to increase the int value of data by 1 so i have put +1 but still the value is empty when i retrieve data

If you meant to increase the existing value of data by once each time you call the function **mMessagesSent()**

You can consider to first take the value from the database if it exists, and increment the value. Create a function in Helper as shown below

```
public Cursor getData(){

    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    String query = "SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_NAME;

    return db.rawQuery(query, null);
}
```

This will return a Cursor to the Database, to read the values in the database. ***Do not put the function mMessagesSent in Helper class, put it in the Activity***. Now in your **mMessagesSent** function, call the above function **getData()** as shown

```
public void mMessagesSent() {
SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
String newId = "default value whatever you have specified";//These two lines may be removed and put outside. If you already have it, then 
int newData = 0;                                           //not required to declare here at all, just replace with those variable names
HelperClassName helper = new HelperClassName(this); //Change the name to your Helper Class name
Cursor data = helper.getData();
while(data.moveToNext()){
    newId = data.getString(0);
    newData = data.getInt(1);
}
ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
contentValues.put(KEY_ID, ID);
contentValues.put(KEY_MESSAGES_SENT, (newData+1)); //Change the value of newData(which is actually your old value) by incrementing
long returnVariable = db.update(TABLE_USER_DATA, contentValues, null, null);
if(returnVariable == -1){
    //-1 means there was an error updating the values
}
else{
//the return value if successful will be number of rows affected by the update
}
}
```

I hope you got your answer.

Comment: How do i call that method? I mean calling that method required 2 parameters and what parameters should i give because i cant use +1 as the method itself is incrementing the value

Comment: I have editted the above code, check if it is working

Comment: while updating its showing updated but while i fetch the data its value is just one... its not going above 1... my edited question has more code